# How to set style with LESS according to body id

Tags: css, less, document-body

Is there any option to set style for some element according to body id with LESS?

I need to do something like this:

```
@body_about = #about_page;

img when (isclass(@body_about)){
   // some style
}
```

this img defintion is deeply buried and I do not want to draw it to the top of... 
Is there any option to do this? Thx for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a conjecture of what you need based off your comment about the "definition is deeply buried" and your first comment to MarmiK's answer. If I am way off what you need here, let me know and I'll remove my answer.

**LESS**

```css
.someClass1 {
  .someClass2 {
    .someClass3 {
      img {
        /* normal code */
        #about_page & {
          /* about page code */
        }  
      }     
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```css
.someClass1 .someClass2 .someClass3 img {
  /* normal code */

}
#about_page .someClass1 .someClass2 .someClass3 img {
  /* about page code */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

just nest the style, 
I understood is that, you want img to have style when it is under #about_page.

in that case you can do this in css

```
#body_about>img{border:0}
```

this will be applied to only `img` under tag with ID `#body_about`

```
 <div id="body_about"> /* this can be any tag <body> or <div> or... */
   <img src="" alt="" />
 </div>
```

I hope this will do :)

Comment: i have set this img defintion deeply buried and i cant't add in there body id... bc i will have this `.class .class .class #body_id > img {}`

Comment: Paste the HTML code for better understanding, read the comments before replying, I have edited the body to div, it works in both ways, paste HTML from the deeply buried file please :) with the same image code you are referring to.

Comment: OK, did u read the title of this topic? "How to set style with LESS"

Comment: Yes but this is simple if you are posting the generated code by less then also it will be fine.. >> open browser>> view source>> and paste the code. you did it. :)